# Compare post date with timestamp in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, date

I have `registered_customers_bod` **function** and I want to get the results in between two dates. For that i am using to and from in where Clause. But I am facing a problem , the record in the database contain a timestamp and I am posting the date YYYY-MM-DD format . Can some one help me to get this timestamp as YYYY-MM-DD format or any other solution for this.

Thanks!!!!

```
 function registered_customers_bod(){
        $this->db->select(array(
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_name',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_email',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_phone',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_no',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_street',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_city',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_status',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_reason_status',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_timestamp',
        ));
        $this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
        $this->db->join('tbl_user_registration', 'tbl_user_registration.user_id=tbl_customer_registration.user_id');
        $this->db->group_by("tbl_customer_registration.cus_id"); //view single record that contain two contact numbers
        $this->db->where('user_timestamp >=',$this->input->post('to'));
        $this->db->where('user_timestamp <=',$this->input->post('from'));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will convert the date string in to a DateTime object that you can then use to get the timestamp.

```
    $to = new DateTime($this->input->post('to'));
    $from = new DateTime($this->input->post('from'));

    $this->db->select(array(
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_name',
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_email',
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_phone',
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile',
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_no',
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_street',
        'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_city',
        'tbl_user_registration.user_status',
        'tbl_user_registration.user_reason_status',
        'tbl_user_registration.user_timestamp',
    ));
    $this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
    $this->db->join('tbl_user_registration', 'tbl_user_registration.user_id=tbl_customer_registration.user_id');
    $this->db->group_by("tbl_customer_registration.cus_id"); //view single record that contain two contact numbers


    $this->db->where('user_timestamp >=',$to->getTimestamp());
    $this->db->where('user_timestamp <=',$from->getTimestamp());
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution...

```
function registered_customers_bod(){
        $this->db->select(array(
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_name',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_email',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_phone',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_mobile',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_no',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_street',
            'tbl_customer_registration.cus_addr_city',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_status',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_reason_status',
            'tbl_user_registration.user_timestamp',
        ));
        $this->db->from('tbl_customer_registration');
        $this->db->join('tbl_user_registration', 'tbl_user_registration.user_id=tbl_customer_registration.user_id');
        $this->db->group_by("tbl_customer_registration.cus_id"); //view single record that contain two contact numbers
        $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(user_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") >=',$this->input->post('to'));
        $this->db->where('STR_TO_DATE(user_timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d") <=',$this->input->post('from'));
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Hope this helps you....

Comment: This answer will work, however, I will always try to avoid using SQL functions in where clauses as potentially this can affect performance.